# OV2640 Webcam not detected

Tags: 11.10, webcam

after much research ang googling, my web cam is still not recognized.
In the time of Ubuntu 11.04 it was working fine. I did a fresh install of 11.10 and not more web cam. 
All the cheese and camera monotor and V4L tests and all failes with "cannot connect to `/dev/video0` or equivalent.

The output of 'lsusb' shows the webcam

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
```

What I noticed is that neither `/dev/v4l` nor `/dev/video*` exists.

If I re-install the v4l package all the `/dev/video*` are created, but no `/dev/v4l`

If I reboot the `/dev/video*` are NOT created.

I think the trouble is that the device are not created at boot time.

I have a DELL Inspiron 1525 and until this fresh install the web cam worked fine.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same webcam; my computer is a Dell XPS M1530. For quite some time I have not been able to use my webcam with the Video4Linux drivers, which I wanted to because they seem to have more active development.

I found out that this webcam is supported by another driver, [UVC Video](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UVC). There is a [list of the supported devices here](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices), and it includes the webcam you mention.

## Use your webcam with UVC Video

Each of the commands shown here you have to run in a terminal window.

1. Check if you have the driver by running `$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo`.

   - If you get an error saying `FATAL: Module uvcvideo not found.`, then you should follow the steps in [this Ubuntu Community Documentation article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UVC) to install the module. After you're done, retry this step.
2. Check if other drivers are loaded, that are conflicting with **uvcvideo**: Run the following commands:

   - `$ sudo modprobe -r videodev`
   - `$ sudo modprobe -r v4l`<kbd>Tab</kbd> (repeat this command for every entry listed when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>).
3. Unload and load back again **uvcvideo** by running:

   `$ sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo`.
4. Open **Cheese** or any other application that will allow you to view through your webcam to see if you are getting video.
5. If this worked,  you should blacklist **videodev** and make **uvcvideo** load everytime you boot.

   - To blacklist **videodev** run the following command:

     `$ sudo echo blacklist videodev >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf`
   - To enforce the load of **uvcvideo** on every boot, run this other command: 

     `$ sudo echo uvcvideo >> /etc/modules`

### Comment

I only wrote this guide because this is how I got this problem fixed in my case; however, I don't know whether each of the commands I cited are mandatory or optimal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

Don't ask me how it works, but what I did is that I reinstalled medibuntu because after the upgrade it was unvalidated. And everything worked again. I did this because I noticed that I also had no more sound.

After upgrading with medibuntu both sound and webcam worked perfectly.