# Making Hercules Classic Link web camera work with Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, webcam

I've got myself a simple webcam today, and it didn't work correctly on Ubuntu 19.10. It blinked its LED and went silent, and in Cheese or Skype the camera does not work, although it's listed in `lsusb` under the name `Guillemot Corp.` and with ID `06f8:300`. The sound works fine though.

I did a little research on the topic and found out about two types of drivers - `gspca` and `uvc`, and that both of them are included in the kernel since 2.6 something.

Then I did a bit more research and found out that my camera is using `gspca_pac7302` driver and throwing errors like `gspca_pac7302 5-3.2.4:1.0: URB error -71, resubmitting`. Interesting that this driver is listed to support this device (06f8:3009) here https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_GSPCA_PAC7302.html

Then, I decided to try out my older laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and there it started to work immediately. I've listed the modules and found out that it is using `uvcvideo`.

Doing some further research and putting simple logic I found this thread [OV2640 Webcam not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84270/ov2640-webcam-not-detected)

But unloading `videodev` did not work for me, because the module was in use, as well as `gspca_main`. Although, `gspca_pac7302` was unloaded successfully with `modprobe -r`, and I could load `uvcvideo` successfully, too. But that didn't help much as the camera is still not working.

Currently, I have these modules loaded:

```
lsmod | grep gspca
gspca_main             24576  1
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       53248  3 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              208896  6 gspca_main,v4l2_common,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

```
lsmod | grep uvc
uvcvideo               98304  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       53248  3 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              208896  6 gspca_main,v4l2_common,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

It seems to me some of them are conflicting or something, am I right? How do I resolve this, do I need to blacklist everything connected to `gspca` and put `uvcvideo` to `/etc/modules`?

Comment: Interesting update: I've tried running Ubuntu 16.04 in a Virtualbox machine, adding the USB device in the settings - and it works flawlessly with cheese. Does this mean that in newer kernel version there's a flawed gspca_pac7302 driver?

Comment: Situation update: web camera works with guvcview, but not with Cheese, Skype or browser